# Circuits need help

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Q2) Im confused with the current flow at R4(8A) and R5(5A) is it going into the node or out of it

[image]

Q5) Is the new load current resistor parallel to the total resistor ?

Comment: "*Q2) Im confused with the current flow at R4(8A) and R5(5A) is it going into the node or out of it*", you're confused? What do you think we're going to be? That's one of the worst schematics I've ever seen. - Regarding Q5, try adding a resistor and check for yourself.

Comment: The answer to Q2 is simple: R6 is **only connected on one side**, so no current can flow, \$I_{R6}\$ = 0 and the direction doesn't even matter. If whoever made that question wants a different answer/thinks a different answer is correct than that person should first learn to **draw a proper schematic** before making questions about using KCL. Geez, how can we expect to have decent EEs in the future if even the teachers make a mess :-(

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie being in education still myself I can confirm the awful schematic techniques used these days to each basic electronics. The majority of questions involving Kirchoffs laws these days all seem to have schematics like that. I have actually been told off for 'defacing' an assignment paper when I redrew a few of them. Standards are definitely going down it seems :( The problem is no one wants to teach because there isn't any money in it!

Comment: Depends on whether you are using Electron Flow or Conventional Current.  In Conventional Current, current goes into the resistor on the positive side on the resistor.  Electron flow, negative.  Load resistor is in series.

Answer (score 0):

> Q2) Im confused with the current flow at R4(8A) and R5(5A) is it going
>   into the node or out of it

Current flows through a resistor from + to -, so both currents are going *into* the node.

> Q5) Is the new load current resistor parallel to the total resistor ?

Yes. The equivalent current source model looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faE45u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>